# Ragged right portion also hyperlinked

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, luatex, hyperlink

In LuaLaTeX, I have ragged right title content which is hyperlinked. Each line end blank also covered hyper link. Kindly suggest get the link upto text only. Please refer the above image

[image]

The below tex code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\def\@maketitle{
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em
 \begin{raggedright}
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \href{www.google.com}{\@title} \par}
  \end{raggedright}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{This is the sample title ragged right and also applied 
hyperlink, the lualatex output pdf each line right side blank 
also covered hyper link box. The pdf hand tool show link on each line 
end blank space also. This is not happen xelatex/pdflatex engine}
\author{}
\date{}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! Please provide a [minimum working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to help us understand your problem.

Comment: @BaskaranNK, not on comment, Please edit your question and add code there.

Comment: Run the file with `PDFLaTeX`, or `XeLaTeX`, etc...

Comment: Pl run in lualatex

Comment: there is nothing simple you can do, when luatex breaks links over lines it links the whole line box. I wouldn't use such a large link anyway, it is a nuisance on a touch screen if large parts of a page are part of a link area.

Comment: Pl run the file in lualatex. We face the problem only in lualatex.

Comment: you should ping people with @UlrikeFischer if you want them to see your comments. Apart from this: I get the same output with pdflatex, only xelatex does it differently.